# MVC 4 custom routing str and int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to have a custom route, like the default one, but this one should accept numeric values as strings. Like 0015. If I leave the parameter type as int, the value passed to the controller method get truncated to 15. And I need 0015.
So what I did, I created the following:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AccRef",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{acc_ref}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", acc_ref = "" },
            constraints: new { acc_ref = @"^\d{1,4}$" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =       UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And the problem is, as I understand, that when I now pass in an integer as "id"

```
@Url.Action("Method", "Controller", new { id = item.ref})
```

from the view, the routing still applies the first route to it and the call fails.

How would you  go about solving this problem with routing?
Is it possible to have two same routing configurations where one accepts int and another string?

Comment: Could you explain a little further as to what your expecting, and what the actual is? i.e. show some link outputs, or is it the request routing that is failing

Comment: It is the routing that is failing with this configuration when I am trying to call the second configuration method type. I have the call that I have described with Url.Action and an action accepting (int id) but it is failing.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do.  Standard routing doesn't care whether it's a string or int.  You just need to set the parameter type in you action method.  So why not just change your action method to accept a string instead of an int, it will just work.

Answer (score 1):

Your AccRef is too greedy.

If you look at the url generated from the Url helper it is:

Controller/Method/id

This matches your first AccRef route as well as the default route.

You have to be more specific with your routes. Also the order you define your routes are important. So you normally want to define greedier routes last.

Phil Haack has a route debugger on nuget (blog post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/)) which can help you identify route issues.

Comment: +1 for the link and you pointed out the correct reason. I just added a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the order like so:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AccRef",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{acc_ref}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", acc_ref = "" },
            constraints: new { acc_ref = @"^\d{1,4}$" }
        );
```

Your current scenario will work with above change but the url "/Home/Index/5" or "/Company/Index/0015" still matches both the routes. This is because the routes are generic (as correctly pointed out by Bigfellahull).

In your case since both the parameter is of type int, both the routes are matched.

Option 1:

You can add a extra string say "Acc" in the route url to make it more specific.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AccRef",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{acc}/{acc_ref}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", acc_ref = "" },
        constraints: new { acc_ref = @"^\d{1,4}$" }
    );
```

In this case the url will change to ".Company/Index/acc/0015".

Option 2:

If you can change the parameter type in action method like so:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
        }
    }
```

The url will match only one route.

Option 1 and 2 are for example only to explain how you can make routes more specific.